# How many databases can i create per sql server license?

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

I have an enterprise edition license for my Sql Server 2008R2 and want to know how many databases can I create on it without additional licensing costs

My question is not about number of databases that can i create on a single instance which is the case answered in several questions but databases without any additional costs.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no licensing limitations to the number of databases you can create.

Answer (score 2):

There are no extra costs per database.  You can have as many databases as will run on your hardware.  Seriously, I've seen a SQL Server 2008 instance with 3,000 databases on it.

(It took a little while to shut down and start up.)